# Better to have ajax inside or outside for-loop or for-loop at the server side? Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, for-loop, implementation, server-side

This is an implementation question.

I have an array of tags which I need to get data for each one. Each of the tags do not need to communicate with eachother. I want to get some data and store it somewhere.

Which is faster?

- Ajax inside a for-loop
- outside the for-loop
- for-loop at the server side?

Comment: Huh? 10 more to go... Test it. Use common sense. Find it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if you need to load a bunch of small data, its better to have one server endpoint that returns the all the data.  It's simpler for the client side and avoids the overhead of many xhrs.  If you have 100 tags, do you really want to invoke 100 xhrs to get them all, not to mention  coordinate the callbacks for all 100?